# input ran out of data; interrupting training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to train a model with the dataset consisting of 160 images (80 -cars, 80 -planes) using image data-augmentation generators on TensorFlow v2.1. I am getting an error when I run the following code :

```
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',
                   metrics=['accuracy'])
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_imagedata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255, shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
test_imagedata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
training_set = \
    train_imagedata.flow_from_directory('data/training_set'
        , target_size=(64, 64), batch_size=32, class_mode='binary')
val_set = \
    test_imagedata.flow_from_directory('data/val_set'
        , target_size=(64, 64), batch_size=32, class_mode='binary')
history=classifier.fit(training_set, steps_per_epoch=30, epochs=30,
                         validation_data=val_set,
                         validation_steps=30)
```

The error is :

```
Found 160 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 40 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/30
 5/30 [====>.........................] - ETA: 5s - loss: 0.5002 - accuracy: 0.8313WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 900 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 30 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
 5/30 [====>.........................] - 2s 416ms/step - loss: 0.5002 - accuracy: 0.8313 - val_loss: 1.6599 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
```

Please suggest what could be done here to rectify this error? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

ImageDataGenerator has a default `batch_size` of 32. you asked to perform 30 steps per epoch, which means 30*32 images per epoch, but you have only 160 images, hence after 5 batches the training collapse. you need to set `steps_per_epoch` to be `floor(num_of_images / batch_size)`.

Comment: Makes sense. However, what if we want to repeat the same images during one epoch? After all, the `ImageDataGenerator` does some image augmentation, so the input won't be the same when we repeat the training. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. If you mean how to use the images again during the same training - you can control this by setting the number of epochs, in each epoch the image will be augmented differently but this is actually the idea in using random augmentations - so the net will "see" different images and will generalize better, instead of memorizing specific images. If you're question is how to be able to reproduce the exact training or experiment at a later time, then you need to make sure you seed everything, so all the random choices will be similar at different experiments.

Comment: no I mean the first thing. I want to repeat the images again, with different augmentation, in the same epoch. Otherwise I need thousands of epochs, because my image set is quite small - it gets large with augmentation.

Comment: I don't think the ```ImageDataGenerator``` class has built in argument to duplicate images within a single epoch, if you must, you can set the generator to load images from data frame (by image path) instead of from a directory, and just duplicate the records in the data frame by yourself. However, the behavior will be the same either by doing that or raising the epochs number. So I don't see a reason not to raise the number of epochs and choosing the workaround.

Comment: yes, thi i how ImageDataGenerator used to work. You could have steps*batch > traingin set. So I think this is something which is changed in a later version of Keras.

Comment: Should that `floor` be changed to `ceil`?

Comment: By the way, [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential) says that `steps_per_epoch` will be automatically determined if it's not specified.